# Should I be concerned about water spilling behind tile wall?

Tags: water, tile, shower

I recently attempted to replace a single handle shower valve (cartridge and all). During removal of the assembly, there was water remaining in the pipes after I had shut off the main. The water leaked out and fell down behind the tile wall of the shower. Should I be concerned about a one-time water spill behind the tile? Is there anyway I can clean it up? The only access is the approximately 6" hole cut in the tile for the valve access.

Answer (score 3):

This should not be a problem. Just make sure to leave the cavity open long enough to let the wet spots dry out.